# Creating a JSON interface in TypeScript without "any."

Tags: typescript

I gather that this may be impossible, given that the return type of the even the native `JSON.parse` function is `any`, but I've been puzzling over how to create a generic JSON type interface in TypeScript. There's [a solution on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3496#issuecomment-128553540) that comes extremely close:

```
type JSONValue = boolean | number | string | JSONObject | JSONArray

interface JSONObject {
  [k: string]: JSONValue
}

interface JSONArray extends Array<JSONValue> {}

const json: JSONObject = {}

console.log(json.gray[9])
```

...but fails to compile in strict mode:

```
~ ❯❯❯ tsc --strict test.ts
test.ts(11,13): error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'JSONValue' has no index signature.
```

My understanding is that because `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` have index values, the union type `JSONValue` should accept one as well; clearly the compiler disagrees. I'm curious for my own edification whether there's any way around this; given that the GitHub issue was from 2015, maybe TypeScript has changed in the interim.

Thanks for any thoughts from more seasoned script typers!

Comment: Union type says "it can be `JSONObject`, but not guaranteed (can also be `boolean` or `string` ...)". You description is suitable for  intersection types. Anyway if you know structure of the object why just not define an interface for it?

Answer (score 3):

```
type JsonObject = { [key: string]: JsonValue };

type JsonValue =
  | null
  | boolean
  | number
  | string
  | JsonValue[]
  | JsonObject;

const stringify = (subject: JsonObject) => {};

stringify({
  foo: 'bar',
});

stringify({
  // @ts-expect-error
  foo: () => {}
});
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAUgzgewHYHkBGArCBjYUC8UA3lANoDWEIAXFHMAE4CWSA5gLq3zIBqAhgBsArtAC+AbgCwAKBmhIsREn7Do+GVCgAfKEiECBG7VDQIEAiHyRGdegLZoIDG3UYtWL7ssEjS7T0roWLhSstLYyPSuzGxMAGYgBFAAFHBCmDjAXIEZuACUBAB8xBIyMvQxrPEgyURGcWa0AORofAxNADQyonmh5W6xCbVGAPQjUAACwHAAtBAAHpC4cwwMCM7Smg0ItMkF+MVEot29QA